# Input sequence / Output number VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a question with an activity which I am attempting.
The question is as follows:

> Steve wants to enter all his staff member's names into a system.  He has the following criteria however:

- Must be last names.
- Must be in the correct format.
- Must calculate and output the number of surnames.

The format must be as the below example:

```
**stevens#smith#thomas#mitchell#adams**
```

To summarise: 
The program must input the character sequence (made up of one or more surenames)
Check that the character sequence has a valid format.
Calculate and output the number of surnames.

This is what I have done so far - however I was wondering if there were any way that I could remove the array and make the code simpler and easier to remember.  Any ideas are much appreciated!

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim sequence As String
    Dim surnamecount As Integer = 0
    Dim sequencearray() As String

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a character sequence")
    sequence = Console.ReadLine
    If Len(sequence) >= 5 And sequence.Substring(0, 2) = "**" And sequence.Substring() Then
        sequencearray = Split(sequence, "#")
        sequencearray(0) = sequencearray(0).Substring(2)
        sequencearray(UBound(sequencearray)) = sequencearray(UBound(sequencearray)).Substring(0, Len(sequencearray(UBound(sequencearray))) - 2)
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(sequencearray)
            Console.WriteLine(sequencearray(i))
            surnamecount = surnamecount + 1
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In it's current state the code doesn't even compile (argument missing for second Substring and If block not ended) and doesn't comply to the rule you gave (where do you print the count of surnames) ? Not sure about that `Len >= 5` it won't prevent to validate this input `**#**`

Comment: @Sehnsucht I've been working on this code for a while - and I'm just stuck on what to do next.  Any suggestions?

Comment: First, update your post with your progress ;what you tempted ; what error, incorrect behaviour etc. Then, I think you can't remove the array (and I d'ont see why you should) ; you need to store the surname somehow (array or other container) because you can't print them when you get them in case of an invalid input. Next you should decompose the problem in simpler steps (ex How can I check it's the start of the input) and write a sample code for each one ; when all the bricks are good you will merge them ; trying to solve the problem as a whole isn't often the good way